# Flatten and merge a panda data frame with multi-index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index, string-matching

As part of a larger data clean up exercise I am using `pandas.Series.str.extractall(pat)` on a data frame column. Calling `extractall()` returns a multi-index due to multiple matches. I would like to flatten and merge the result from `extractall()` into a data frame.

I've spent countless hours with various combinations of `apply`, `agg`, `groupby`, `join` and haven't made any progress. Any suggestions?

**Simplified example**

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([["cat 123"], ["hat dog 36776"], ["dog 345"], ["fish 456890 hat"]], columns=['A'])
pat = r'(?:(?P<Mammal>(?:cat)|(?:dog))|(?P<Fish>(?:fish))|(?P<Hat>(?:hat)))'
df_ea = df['A'].str.extractall(pat)
```

Results in this table

|  |  | Mammal | Fish | Hat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | match |  |  |  |
| 0 | 0 | cat | NaN | NaN |
| 1 | 0 | NaN | NaN | hat |
| 1 |  | dog | NaN | NaN |
| 2 | 0 | dog | NaN | NaN |
| 3 | 0 | NaN | fish | NaN |
| 1 |  | NaN | NaN | hat |

**Desired result**

```py
df_test = pd.DataFrame([["cat", "", ""],
                        ["dog", "", "hat"],
                        ["dog", "", ""],
                        ["", "fish", "hat"]],
                       columns=['Mammal', 'Fish', 'Hat'])
```

|  | Mammal | Fish | Hat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | cat |  |  |
| 1 | dog |  | hat |
| 2 | dog |  |  |
| 3 |  | fish | hat |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df_ea=df_ea.reset_index(drop=True).fillna('')
```

you've already done a great job you're only missing this last line

Answer (score 3):

You could use `groupby` as follows:

`df_ea = df['A'].str.extractall(pat).groupby(level=0).first()`

This will be the result:

```
Mammal  Fish   Hat
0    cat  None  None
1    dog  None   hat
2    dog  None  None
3   None  fish   hat
```